# Saving Images Inside A Loop

Tags: matlab

Hi I have a loop and each time it separates and image and i want to save it automatically with different image name. I have following code 
figure

```
for n=1:Ne
    [r,c] = find(L==n);
    n1=imagen(min(r):max(r),min(c):max(c));
    imshow(~n1);
    imwrite(~n1, test.jpg);
    pause(0.5)
end
```

Problem I have is in imwrite(~n1, test.jpg); it only saves one image while I need to save it so that all are saved like test1.jpg, test2.jpg so on ...anyone has an idea how to do that?
Thank you for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like to use something like this:

```
imwrite(~n1, sprintf('test%05d.jpg', n)); %this would pad with 5 zeros
```

to pad the filename with zeros, so they are nicely sorted in the diretory.

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
imwrite(~n1, ['test' num2str(n) '.jpg']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't really used imwrite in Matlab much but I know you would normally just concatenate strings in order to change the file name based on the loop value.  So you could just do something like the following code:

```
imwrite(~n1, sprintf('test%d.jpg', n));
```

You could use something like [sprintf](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sprintf.html) with a %d modifier to add an integer into a string.

Comment: I edited my answer to show a concatenation that follows Matlab standards.